# htpasswd: cannot create file /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users

Tags: nagios

I just installed nagios on CentOS 6.5. While creating the default auth. user:

```
htpasswd –c /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin
```

Here is what I got:

```
htpasswd: cannot create file /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users
```

The command was run as root, `/usr/local/nagios/etc/` exists, and SELinux is enabled. What might be the problem?

Comment: SELinux is probably denying, check /var/log/audit/audit.log

Comment: In my own case, the directory I was using did not exist.

Comment: It's the directory bit. First `cd /usr/local/nagios/etc` then `htpasswd -c htpasswd.users nagiosadmin`.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solved the problem by first creating the file manually. Here is what I did: my apache2 files are in `/usr/local/apache2/` . So I created a directory `mkdir passwd` in `/apache2/` directory and created a file in that passwd directory by running `touch passwords`. Then I finally ran `htpasswd -c /usrl/local/apache2/passwd/passwords flicker` . Please note that flicker is the username.

Answer (score 1):

Just create all the subsequent folders and the final file manually and then try the command again. I did the same and it worked.

Comment: (1) The question says that the directory exists.  (2) The first answer already suggested creating the file ‘‘manually’’.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on Ubuntu 14.04, I found that the directory that the `htpasswd` file was supposed to be created in didn't exist. Simply creating the folder and changing ownership to Nagios did the trick. Note also that the same problem affected creation of the config file, so running `make install-config` before restarting Nagios might be necessary:

```
$ ls -al /usr/local/nagios/
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  7 root   root   4096 May 30 20:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root   root   4096 May 30 20:34 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 nagios nagios 4096 May 30 20:34 bin
drwxrwxr-x  2 nagios nagios 4096 May 30 20:34 libexec
drwxrwxr-x  2 nagios nagios 4096 May 30 20:34 sbin
drwxrwxr-x 14 nagios nagios 4096 May 30 20:34 share
drwxrwxr-x  5 nagios nagios 4096 May 30 20:34 var

$ sudo mkdir /usr/local/nagios/etc
[sudo] password ...
$ sudo chown -R nagios:nagios /usr/local/nagios/etc
$ sudo htpasswd -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin
New password:
```

---

```
$ sudo service nagios start
Configuration file /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg not found. Exiting.
$ sudo make install-config
/usr/bin/install -c -m 775 -o nagios -g nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc
/usr/bin/install -c -m 775 -o nagios -g nagios -d /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects
/usr/bin/install -c -b -m 664 -o nagios -g nagios sample-config/nagios.cfg /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg
/usr/bin/install -c -b -m 664 -o nagios -g nagios sample-config/cgi.cfg /usr/local/nagios/etc/cgi.cfg
/usr/bin/install -c -b -m 660 -o nagios -g nagios sample-config/resource.cfg /usr/local/nagios/etc/resource.cfg
/usr/bin/install -c -b -m 664 -o nagios -g nagios sample-config/template-object/templates.cfg /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/templates.cfg
/usr/bin/install -c -b -m 664 -o nagios -g nagios sample-config/template-object/commands.cfg /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg
/usr/bin/install -c -b -m 664 -o nagios -g nagios sample-config/template-object/contacts.cfg /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/contacts.cfg
/usr/bin/install -c -b -m 664 -o nagios -g nagios sample-config/template-object/timeperiods.cfg /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/timeperiods.cfg
/usr/bin/install -c -b -m 664 -o nagios -g nagios sample-config/template-object/localhost.cfg /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/localhost.cfg
/usr/bin/install -c -b -m 664 -o nagios -g nagios sample-config/template-object/windows.cfg /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/windows.cfg
/usr/bin/install -c -b -m 664 -o nagios -g nagios sample-config/template-object/printer.cfg /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/printer.cfg
/usr/bin/install -c -b -m 664 -o nagios -g nagios sample-config/template-object/switch.cfg /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/switch.cfg

*** Config files installed ***
```

Remember, these are *SAMPLE* config files.  You'll need to read
the documentation for more information on how to actually define
services, hosts, etc., to fit your particular needs.

```
$ sudo service nagios start
Starting nagios: done.
```

Comment: I approved your edit but you should really merge the two accounts so you can freely edit your own posts. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts